# Solve the system of equation with answers as x=___+___s

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve the system:

\begin{cases}
-4x_1 + x_2=3 \\
8x_1-2x_2=-6
\end{cases}

I need the solution in the form of:

\begin{cases}
x_1=\underline{\hspace{1cm}}+\underline{\hspace{1cm}}\times s\\[0.3em]
x_2=\underline{\hspace{1cm}}+\underline{\hspace{1cm}}\times s\\[0.3em]
\end{cases}

I've attempted to due this multiple times and end with the same answer each time.

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-4 & 1 &  & \phantom13 \\
8 & -2 &  &         -6 \\
\end{array}

Multiplying row 2 by $\frac12$:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-4 & 1 &  & \phantom13 \\
4 & -1 &  &         -3 \\
\end{array}

Adding row 1 to row 2:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-4 & 1 &  & \phantom13 \\
0 & 0 &  &         0 \\
\end{array}

thus $x_2$  is a free variable, and:

\begin{align*}
x_1 ={}& \frac34-\frac14s \\
x_2 ={}& 0 + 1s
\end{align*}

Is what I get for my answer.

Comment: Where is $x_3$?

Comment: x_3 isn't supposed to be there. I copied the code and made a mistake since I can't figure out the mathjax programming.

Comment: And... I wonder what do you want to ask. is it a proof verification?

Comment: in general if rank of matrix is less than number of variable you need to find null space. it will give you solution for your system where RHS is set to zero. if you add any solution (like [0,-3/4] in your case) to any point from null space it also will be solution.

Comment: There is a sign error in your expression for $x_1$.  Write the row reduced form back out as an equation, $-4x_1 + x_2 = 3$, and it should become clear to you why this was incorrect (i.e. you should divide by $-4$).

Answer (score 1):

Reading off from your last matrix equation, you have
$$-4x_1 + x_2 = 3 \Rightarrow x_1 = 1/4 x_2 - 3/4$$

Now choose $x_2 = s$. Then $x_2 = 0 + 1s$ is equivalent to making that choice, and substituting $x_2 = s$ gives $x_1 = 1/4s - 3/4$ in the first equation.

$$x_2 = 0 + 1s$$
$$x_1 = - 3/4 + 1/4s$$

Now if $x$ is a vector, $$x = (x_1, x_2) = (-3/4 + 1/4s, 0 + s) = (-3/4, 0) + (1/4, 1)s$$

or written more suggestively,

$$x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-3/4 + 1/4s \\
0 + s
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-3/4 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/4s \\
s
\end{bmatrix} =  
\begin{bmatrix}
-3/4 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/4 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}s $$

Which is in the form requested.

Comment: Looks like I just had my signs backwards. Not sure how that happened but  looking at it again now I see it. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to everyone now and then.